# SSL API request fails as of today: "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, ssl, nginx

we have a C# .NET 4.5 desktop application which was released half a year ago and ran fine until today. 
On start-up the app sends a JSON request to our Web API but it fails with

```
{"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}
```

I have found some other topics where the solution was this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

It works for our app as well but the big question remains:
Why did it work on thousands of computers for half a year?

The first thing I thought of was: Daylight Savings Time, the time change happened today. So I've checked the server time, renewed the SSL certificate and rebooted the server but the problem remains.

Any ideas?

App:
.NET 4.5

Server:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
nginx/1.11.10

**Update**
After disabling Cloudflare for the domain, the issue is gone. I don't know what exactly causes this but I suspect that it has in fact sth. to do with DST time zone and SSL handshake.

Comment: Are you in the United States? Daylight Saving Time ends Sunday November 5th this year (2017). There are [*many* countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country) where DST does end today. Does your server perhaps have a different locale?

Comment: Hi Bob, me and the server are located in Germany. But it seems like you are on the right track: After disabling Cloudflare for the API, the issue is gone. I don't really understand why the issue is Cloudflare and want to look deeper into this but I will update the question with my latest findings. Thanks!

Comment: Guess you're a Cloudflare free plan user? I think this issue mostly impacts free user as uses CF's free certificates. In this case, I wouldn't expect the issue sort out quick by CF for us "free users".

Comment: hi @29Palms just FYI, if you contact "prdonahue" on twitter, they seems giving a free dedicated certificate as temporary solution to this issue, till they roll out the fix later.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I'll leave CF deactivated for the moment and rollout the updated version forcing TLS1.2 when this is officially patched. Prepared for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have exactly the same issue.

Appears Cloudflare dropped supporting TLS 1.0/1.1 this morning (in our case).
I've raised this to Cloudflare. But no response from them yet.

Meanwhile I asked question in their community (https://community.cloudflare.com/t/was-the-tls-1-0-1-1-not-supported-since-4am-utc-2017-10-30/7586/3).  There're other users impacted too.

My initial thoughts was DST, but today is the second day after DST switch, plus our server/client runs on the same server, using UTC. So it can't be due to a DST issue (unless something in Cloudflare internally)

---

The solution for now is like what you did, force client to use TLS 1.2+